# How to configure asp.net mvc route for the url "http://localhost:1234/#/animal"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to configure a route for the url pattern "http://localhost:1234/#/animal"

Basically I want different actions to be executed for "http://localhost:1234" and "http://localhost:1234/#/animal"

So I added a route like below.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "DefaultHashed",
                url: "#/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "HashedIndex", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

But it still uses the Default route shown below and not DefaultHashed route. What am i missing?

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Edit:
This is an ASP.NET MVC with Angular SPA. The Index action of default controller is shown below.

```
 public ActionResult Index(int id)
        {
            if (User?.IsAuthenticated)
            {
               return View("/dist/Index.cshtml");
            }
            return RedirectToAction("SignIn", "Authentication");
        }
```

Here I want to redirect to external url if the posted url is  "http://localhost:1234". if not I should load the angular page.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to do this in MVC, as url portion after # is trimmed and it is not posted to the server. This type is routing schemes are common in Single Page Application built with frameworks like Angular or React

Comment: @Yogi thanks for the info. But I need to achieve this some how. I have edited question for more details. Just wondering if there is any alternative?

Comment: Bascially **you can't**.  The server never recieves the fragment identifier.